# Extract contents from XML file

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2010

I have a C# application that uses a button to generate a file. Currently, I want to use C# to extract out contents from the XML file and pass it as a string. For example in my XML file, I have a tag name. I want to use c# to extract the name from the XML file. How should I go about achieving it? Below is the sample code I have currently. The entire process must be carried out using a button click.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    XElement xml = XElement.Load("C:\\Windows 7.xml"); 
    IEnumerable<XElement> propertyIDs = xml.Descendants("PropertyId");

    foreach (XElement child in xml.Elements())
    {
        XElement row = child.Element("my:VM_Name");
        string test = xml.ToString();
        Console.WriteLine(test);
    }    
}
```

Please access this link to view my xml file: http://pastebin.com/NKhBb4Zh

Comment: Your code looks pretty good.  I don't understand the question; what is it you want to have happen in the body of your `foreach` loop?

Comment: What are you trying to do that doesn't work? Do you get an exception? What doesn't look right?

Comment: @Kirk Woll using Console.WriteLine(xml.Value); I am able to display the contents in my xml file. I want to extract the contents for each elements and pass it to a string in c#.

Comment: I want to extract out an XML content from an XML file and parse it to a string.

Comment: @dwayne, define "contents".  Do you mean the outer-xml?  Do you mean the inner-xml?  The text content?  Or the value of some or all of the attributes?

Comment: If you don't mind editing your question and add some of the XML you're trying to parse, what you currently get and what you'd want, it would be clearer and I'm sure you'd get a very helpful answer within a few mins! :-D

Comment: @Kirk Woll I added this code XElement name = xml.Element("my:VM_Name"); string test = xml.ToString(); Console.WriteLine(test); But I am still unable to extract out Windows 7 from the XML tag.

Comment: @Kirk Woll i get this error The ':' character, hexadecimal value 0x3A, cannot be included in a name.

Comment: The `my` part is the XML namespace. It is used differently. See this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb943852.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I rewrote your example and changed it to make use of the XmlDocument class. As there is the **my** Namespace I had to add a *NameSpaceManager*. using this you may even select a spefic node.

```
        string url = @"e:\temp\data.xml";

        XmlDocument doc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(url);
        XmlElement docElement = doc.DocumentElement;

        /// loop through all childNodes
        foreach (XmlNode childNode in docElement.ChildNodes)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(childNode.Name + ": " + childNode.InnerText);
        }

        XmlNamespaceManager mgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
        mgr.AddNamespace("my", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/myXSD/2011-05-27T03:57:48");

        /// use the given XmlNamespaceManager to select a specific element
        XmlNode node = docElement.SelectSingleNode("my:VM_DiskSize", mgr);
        /// use innerText for node text and value for attributes only
        Console.WriteLine("\n" + node.Name + ": " + node.InnerText);
```

hth

Comment: Console.WriteLine("\n" + node.Name + ": " + node.InnerText);  is giving me error. NullException

Comment: sry there was a spelling error in the namespace .. just copy my code and try it - should work now

Comment: just to side track do you know how to add double quotes? This does not work. string VMname = "\"node3.InnerText\"";

Comment: string VMname = "\"" + node3.InnerText + "\""; // should do the trick

Answer (score 1):

The comments you added to your question were very helpful.  In particular:

> I added this code:

```
XElement name = xml.Element("my:VM_Name"); 
string test = xml.ToString(); 
Console.WriteLine(test);
```

> But I am still unable to extract out Windows 7 from the XML tag

And:

> i get this error The ':' character, hexadecimal value 0x3A, cannot be included in a name.

Let's start with the error first.  You cannot pass to the `Element` method an `ns:name` pair as you've done.  With this API, the namespace (`ns`) must be supplied programatically via the `XName` type.  So instead, that line should read:

```
XElement name = xml.Element(XName.Get("VM_Name", "my"));
```

Here we pass the qualified name as an actual `XName` and not as a colon-delimited string as it originates.  Pay attention to the order; the namespace comes *second* using this syntax.

Now, once you have done all this, the other line in which you have a problem is:

```
string test = xml.ToString();
```

Here, `xml` refers to your root XML node whereas what you actually want is, presumably, the element for which you just queried:  `xml.Element(XName.Get("VM_Name", "my"))`.  Furthermore, to get the text contents of that node, you should use the `Value` property.  I suspect what you really want is:

```
string test = name.Value;
```

Comment: I replace the code to         private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            XElement xml = XElement.Load("C:\\Windows 7.xml"); 
            IEnumerable<XElement> propertyIDs = xml.Descendants("PropertyId"); 
            foreach(XElement propertyID in propertyIDs) 
            {
                XElement name = xml.Element(XName.Get("VM_Name", "my"));
                string test = name.Value;
                Console.WriteLine(test);
            } }

Comment: I am getting the error NullReferenceException under String test = name.Value;

Comment: @dwayne, the `Element` method will return `null` if the element is not found.  Please *edit* your question and include the contents of `C:\\Windows 7.xml`.